Office Add-In: Excel API Set 1.16 Not Available When Using Local Office.js Version
I'm developing an Excel Add-In using the latest npm version of the JavaScript API and I'm encountering an issue with the latest Excel API set (1.16) functionality.
I’m trying to access the valueAsJson property from a RangeObject, which is part of Excel API 1.16. I installed the latest version 1.1.93 which is supposed to include this functionality. However, when loading this property from a Range Object it fails and when debugging I can see that the Range instance does not have a valueAsJson property. I did everything according to the documentation:

Installed the latest version of @microsoft/office-js (v1.1.93).
Added the script reference in my HTML file like this:
<script src="/assets/office-js/office.js"></script>
Most of the functionality works, but anything related to Excel API set 1.16 (like valueAsJson) is not available and can also not be found in the correpsonding office.d.ts file.
When switching to the CDN version of Office.js, everything works as expected, but we need the add-in to work offline, so using the CDN is not an option.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how it can be fixed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The npm version of office.js (@microsoft/office-js (v1.1.93).) is no longer being updated. To use a local copy of office.js, you have to copy the files from the CDN.

Hi! Thanks for your answer. I saw that a new version (1.1.94) was published just 16 days ago. However, with that version I also encounter the same problem. Do you know what the new versions are for? And is there any way to get all CDN files at once? I can only copy the ones that my system needs when working with the add-in (files for my language, my operating system,...) but I did not figure out how I could get all CDN files.

As far as I know, you have to download each file manually. You could search the internet for web scraping tools and see if any of them would simplify the task.

Thanks again for clarifying. Can you tell me what is then still released in newer npm versions of office.js (such as 1.1.94)?
